# CherryPy Tool: How to register custom tool correctly?

Tags: cherrypy

I want to create a simple tool but fail to register it correctly. As soon as I add it to any method I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Toolbox' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
```

I tried

```
cherrypy.tools.authenticate = cherrypy.Tool('before_handler', authenticate)
```

and

```
@cherrypy.tools.register('before_handler')
def authenticate():
```

The issue I likely have is placing the function in the wrong place. I have a main file launching the server and all apps:

```
#config stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.engine.unsubscribe('graceful', cherrypy.log.reopen_files)
    logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_CONF)
    cherrypy.tree.mount(app1(), '/app1')
    cherrypy.tree.mount(app2(), '/app2')
    cherrypy.quickstart(app3)
```

This file is launched by a systemd unit.

If I put the `authenticate` function in the config area, it doesn't work. If i put it in one of the apps directly and only use it in that app, it doesn't work. Always the same error.

So where do I have to place it to make this work?

Comment: I don't think that `AttributeError` is happening with the `register` handler. If yes, then maybe you're doing something weird in your app.

Comment: Another case of me falling into the function definition order matters in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another case of me falling into the python definition order matters trap.

Doesn't work:

```
class MyApp(object): 

    #....

@cherrypy.tools.register('on_start_resource')
def authenticate():
    #....
```

Works:

```
@cherrypy.tools.register('on_start_resource')
def authenticate():
    #....

class MyApp(object):
```

Comment: Alternatively, use config instead of decorators.